particle based coin collection system collecting multiple times per coin
I have a particle system that sprays coins out of the enemies apon death that have colliders so that when the player walks over to them he will collect them but I think the coins are being collected multiple times per particle.
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class CoinParticle : MonoBehaviour
{
    public ParticleSystemForceField playerField;
    public GameObject Player;
    public PlayerController controller;
    PlayerStatsManager playerStats;
    public ParticleSystem ps;
    List<ParticleSystem.Particle> particles = new List<ParticleSystem.Particle>();

    private void Awake()
    {
        playerField = FindAnyObjectByType<ParticleSystemForceField>();
        Player = FindAnyObjectByType<PlayerController>().gameObject;
        controller = Player.GetComponent<PlayerController>();
        //playerStats = Player.GetComponent<PlayerStatsManager>();
        ps = gameObject.GetComponent<ParticleSystem>();
        ps.trigger.SetCollider(0, Player.GetComponent<Collider>());
    }

    public void dropCoins(Vector2Int coinDropRange)
    {
        ParticleSystem.Burst burst = new ParticleSystem.Burst(0.0f, (short)coinDropRange.x, (short)coinDropRange.y, 0.01f);
        ps.emission.SetBursts(new ParticleSystem.Burst[] { burst });
        ps.Play();
    }

    private void OnParticleTrigger()
    {
        int triggeredParticles = ps.GetTriggerParticles(ParticleSystemTriggerEventType.Enter, particles);

        for (int i = 0; i < triggeredParticles; i++)
        {
            ParticleSystem.Particle p = particles[i];
            p.remainingLifetime = 0f;
            controller.goldAmount++;
            
            particles[i] = p;
        }

        ps.SetTriggerParticles(ParticleSystemTriggerEventType.Enter, particles);
    }
}

using System.Collections;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class EnemyStats : MonoBehaviour
{
    Encounter encounter;

    [SerializeField] float health;
    public bool isAlive;
    [SerializeField] Vector2Int coinDropRange;
    private float currentHealth;
    [SerializeField] Image healthBarSprite;
    [SerializeField] GameObject deathParticle;
    [SerializeField] Transform deathTransform;
    [SerializeField] GameObject coinParticle;
    [SerializeField] Transform coinTransform;

    public bool inRange;

    private float lerpDuration;

    private void Start()
    {
        isAlive = true;
        encounter = GetComponentInParent<Encounter>();
        currentHealth = health;
        lerpDuration = .5f;
    }

    public void death()
    {
        if (!isAlive) return; // Prevent multiple calls

        isAlive = false;

        GameObject coinGO = Instantiate(coinParticle, coinTransform.position, coinTransform.rotation);
        CoinParticle coinPS = coinGO.GetComponent<CoinParticle>();
        coinPS.dropCoins(coinDropRange);

        Instantiate(deathParticle, deathTransform.position, deathTransform.rotation);
        encounter.currentMonsters--;
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }

    public IEnumerator DamageMonster(float damage)
    {
        float time = 0;
        float endValue = currentHealth - damage;

        if (endValue <= 0) endValue = 0;

        while (time < lerpDuration)
        {
            currentHealth = Mathf.Lerp(currentHealth, endValue, time / lerpDuration);
            healthBarSprite.fillAmount = currentHealth / health;
            time += Time.deltaTime;
            yield return null;
        }

        currentHealth = endValue;

        if (currentHealth <= 0 && isAlive)
        {
            Debug.Log("Monster dead");
            death();
        }
    }
}


for instance a skeleton should only drop 10 coins (sometimes it looks like they just drop more than that even though my code says they should only be able to drop that much idk) but the count would go up by like 30.
I just can't think of how to make sure each particle is only picked up once
I tried to make sure the enemies death() function wasn't being called multiple times thinking it was just instantiating more then one particle system but that wasn't it.

Hm interesting, in the API I didn't find a constructor for ParticleSystem.Burst with the signature (float, short, short, float) can you confirm what exactly this signature expects / what your arguments mean?
